# Problem on differentiation of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question is to find the value of $f$ differentiated partially with respect to $x$ (say $f_x$) at $(0,0)$
And the find the value of $f$ differentiated partially with respect to $y$ (say $f_y$) at $(0,0$)

I find $f_x(0,0) =1$ 
But I am unable to find $f_y(0,0)$

Please help[image]
**NOTE:** Consider $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ in the image.

Comment: I tried to find fy(0,0) using its formula but I am confused as to take 1 or -1

Comment: If the derivative is different on both sides of the point of interest, what does that tell you about the derivative at the point of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just 0. Recall partial derivative definition:

> In mathematics, a partial derivative of a function of several
>   variables is its derivative with respect to one of those variables,
>   with the others held constant

So fy(0, 0) is just going to be:

$$fy(0, 0) = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{f(0, \Delta y) - f(0, 0)}{\Delta y}$$

And from the function definition, when $x = 0, f = 0$, so $f(0, \Delta y) - f(0, 0)$ is always zero, which makes the above limit to be zero. And more generally, for this function $fy(0, y) = 0,  \forall y$.